# React, create an array of arrays variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the datatables.net library with React to generate nice-looking tables. To get a working example I hard-coded a variable `dataSet` and sent it as a prop to the  component like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { TblFunc } from "./TblFunc"

export default function AppFunc() {
  const dataSet = [
    ["site1", "device1"],
    ["site1", "device2"],
    ["site1", "device3"],
    ["site1", "device4"],
    ["site1", "device5"],
    ["site1", "device6"],
    ["site1", "device7"],
    ["site1", "device8"],
    ["site1", "device9"],
    ["site2", "device1"],
    ["site2", "device2"],
    ["site2", "device3"],
    ["site2", "device4"],
    ["site2", "device5"],
    ["site2", "device6"],
    ["site2", "device7"],
    ["site2", "device8"]
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      <TblFunc data={dataSet} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

This generates this output:[image]

Now, instead of hard coding the `dataSet` variable, I want to generate it automatically by calling an API. I need to create an Array of Arrays object to mimic `dataSet`. The API returns an object like this:

```
{
    "site1": [
      "device-a01",
      "device-a02",
      "device-b01",
      "device-b02"
    ],
    "site2": [
      "device-a01",
      "device-a02",
      "device-b01",
      "device-b02",
      "device-c01",
      "device-c02"
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
import React from "react"
import { TblFunc } from "./TblFunc"

export default function AppFunc() {

  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState([])

  function buildTableData(site, device) {
    const hubValue = []
   
    hubValue.push(site)
    hubValue.push(device)
    
    return hubValue

  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await fetch("https://api.com/api/devices/")
      const data = await res.json()
      
      Object.entries(data).forEach(([site, devices]) => {
        const _tableData = devices.map(device => buildTableData(site, device))
        console.log(_tableData)

        setTableData(_tableData)

      })
      
    }
    getData()
    
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <TblFunc data={dataSet} /> // THIS WORKS */}
      <TblFunc data={tableData} />
      {JSON.stringify(tableData)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When printing `tableData` to the screen I get this:

```
[["site1","device01"],["site1","device02"],["site1","device03"],["site1","device04"],["site1","device05"],["site1","device06"]["site1","device07"]]
```

I believe I have generated an Array of Array's object but for some reason when I pass it to the `<TableFunc />` component it does not populate the table. This leads me to believe that `tableData` is not matching the `dataSet` object.

This is what `<TableFunc />` looks like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import $ from 'jquery'

export function TblFunc(props) {

$.DataTable = require('datatables.net')
const tableRef = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(tableRef.current)
    const table = $(tableRef.current).DataTable(
        {
            data: props.data,
                columns: [
                    { title: "Site"},
                    { title: "Device"}
                ],
                destroy: true  // I think some clean up is happening here
        }
    )
    // Extra step to do extra clean-up.
    return function() {
        console.log("Table destroyed")
        table.destroy()
    }
},[])

    return (
        <div>
            <table className="display" width="100%" ref={ tableRef }></table>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: You're using `forEach` and setting the state at the end of each iteration, so you will only ever have the last `entry` refactored. You should instead refactor the full `Object.entries` array, and then set state.

Comment: I think @pilchard is probably right. But also, I'd like to add - use the browser's debugger and step through execution. In Chrome, choose View -> Developer -> Developer Tools, click source pane, find your file and set a breakpoint. Alternatively, add a "debugger;" statement in your JS code. Stepping through will make it much easier to tell what is going on with your logic.

Comment: @pilchard, i see what you're saying, but even with only the last ```entry``` being written to ```tableData``` have i generated the ```tableData``` object correctly as an Array of Arrays? I can't even get the last ```entry``` to display in the table.

Comment: It looks like because you initially pass an empty array the table doesn't update when you finally populate the array in the `useEffect`. A quick fix is to conditionally render the first render `{!!tableData.length && <TblFunc data={tableData} />}`, but you'll want to troubleshoot the actual rerender issue. (I would recommend using a React ready table library rather than one that relies on jQuery and direct DOM manipulation) Here's a quick [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datatables-net-w-react-q3h3qq)

Comment: The above comment is accurate, but I overlooked your second `useEffect` in the `TblFunc` component. Simply add `props.data` to the dependency array. `useEffect(() => { const table = $(tableRef.current).DataTable({ ...}, [props.data]);` Updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datatables-net-w-react-q3h3qq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @pilchard, Adding ```props.data``` to the ```useEffect``` in ```<TblFunc />``` worked. Also, thank you for introducing me to ```flatMap```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table update relies on the jquery code in the `useEffect` in your `TblFunc` component, but you have passed an empty dependency array so the table is never rebuilt after the first render. Simply add `props.data` to the dependency array and the table should update as expected after the fetch completes in the parent's `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const table = $(tableRef.current).DataTable(
    {
      data: props.data,
      columns: [
        { title: "Site" },
        { title: "Device" }
      ],
      destroy: true  // I think some clean up is happening here
    }
  )

  return function () {
    console.log("Table destroyed")
    table.destroy()
  }
}, [props.data])
//  ^^^^^^^^^^ add relevant dependency to trigger rerender
```

Secondly, you're using `forEach` and setting the state at the end of each iteration, so you will only ever have the last entry refactored. You should instead refactor the full `Object.entries` array, and then set state.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch("https://api.com/api/devices/")
    const data = await res.json()

    const _tableData = Object.entries(data).flatMap(([site, devices]) =>
      devices.map((device) => [site, device])
    );

    setTableData(_tableData);
  }
  getData();
}, []);
```

The above uses a streamlined refactoring method using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with a nested [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the inner `devices` array.

```js
const data = { "site1": ["device-a01", "device-a02", "device-b01", "device-b02"], "site2": ["device-a01", "device-a02", "device-b01", "device-b02", "device-c01", "device-c02"] };

const _tableData = Object.entries(data).flatMap(([site, devices]) =>
  devices.map((device) => [site, device])
);

console.log(_tableData);
```

Example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datatables-net-w-react-q3h3qq?file=/src/App.js).